# Identify average number of signal in a one-minute trade dataset in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strategy modeled in excel and generated buy/sell signals based on a one minute market data.

I would like to know the average number of signals generated in an hour.  The data looks like this.

[image: Excel sampe data in image format]

Thanks for your help.

I am trying to avoid any complex usage of user defined functions.

regards
Gopal

Comment: Average per **minute** or average per **hour** ???

Comment: Did you try `=countifs(`?

Comment: This is what I tried and I am able to get for the first hour. I need to write a code, which skips to the beginning of the next hour and gets the count and so on.

Comment: =COUNTIF(OFFSET(B15,0,9,MATCH(B15+TIME(1,0,0),B15:$B$713,1)-1,1),"sell")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(B15,0,9,MATCH(B15+TIME(1,0,0),B15:$B$713,1)-1,1),"buy").  First row starts from B15.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Date is in column A and signal in column F, labels in row 1 and no other data in those columns, try

=(COUNTIF(F:F,"<>")-1)/((COUNTA(A:A)-1)/60)

Comment: Might work if the data is grouped in hours.  The data is market data - from 9.15 AM to 3.30 PM and then the second day starts.  Your COUNTA(A:A)-1)/60 assumes that there is 60 rows for each hour, which is not the case.  But nice try. My bad that I didnt mention this.

Comment: Also, the COUNTIF(F:F,"<>") adds up the blanks boxes too - formula field.

Comment: Well, maybe you should put out ALL the details of your requirement into the question instead of adding them piecemeal and wasting people's time.

Comment: well, sorry about that.  There is no additional requirement.  To sum it up again, the data is market data minute by minute starting from 9.15 AM to 3.30 PM. This runs for days.  I generate a signal based on a strategy and that signal is there int he right most column.  I want to know the Average number of signals generated every hour.  Thanks for your help

Comment: You say the data is minute by minute, but then you say that there are not 60 rows for each hour. Can you explain that?

Comment: Between 3.15 and 3.30 (market end time), you will not have 60 rows. Data during that period should be averaged out separately and then start fresh next morning. Thanks

Comment: come on! give me a break.  I have already mentioned the data is market data minute by minute starting from 9.15 AM to 3.30 PM. I don't have a provision to send you the file. If you focus a bit more, you would have realized that there will be 375 rows for a day - and that is not going to be evenly divisible by 60. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: Yah, anyway. See how far your attitude gets you here. Have a nice life.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wishes.  I will take care, if it is important to address the attitude. I suggest you do that too.  Will leave it there.